# FFT, padding, IFFT and plot in time domain

Tags: matlab, fft, signal-analysis, ifft, zero-padding

I performed an FFT with some zero padding and would like to transform it back to time domain. When I plot the signal it looks wrong. Is it because of the padding used in the FFT? How can I make it right? here is my code for doing the IFFT:

```
NFFT=4301;
AvIFFT = ifft(FFTavg.dat,NFFT);
plot(real(AvIFFT))
```

And I get this plot:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

ps: I have asked this question on matworks but no success as yet.

EDIT:

As suggested in the comment and answer below, I tried fftshift:

```
NFFT = 4301;
FFTshifted = fftshift(FFTavg.dat);
AvIFFT  = ifftshift(FFTshifted,NFFT);   
plot(real(AvIFFT))
```

Here is the plot:

[image]

Comment: look up the MATLAB function `fftshift()`.

Comment: have you tried `fftshift()` yet?

Comment: what does it do to your time-domain plot?

Comment: As I do ifft that should be the time-domain plot, right?

Comment: apply to this: NFFT=4301;
AvIFFT = ifft(FFTavg.dat,NFFT); before this:
plot(real(AvIFFT))

Comment: Not sure I'm getting you sorry. I believe I did this in my example above, didn't I?

Comment: i don't see an `fft()` being performed at all in that last example.  `fftshift()` does not do an FFT.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My initial data (FFTavg.dat) is the result of the fft.

Comment: the bottom plot looks like frequency-domain data, the top plot looks like time-domain data.  now i really don't know what it is that you have, and what it is that you're trying to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

user3406207: I'm not sure what you're trying to do because I don't know the meaning of your words "wrong" and "right."  But we *can* say, if you perform time-domain zero padding on an original unpadded $x1[n]$ input sequence you'll produce some longer-length $x2[n]$ sequence. The $X2[m]$ fft of your $x2[n]$ sequence will be an *interpolated* version of (more freq-domain samples than) the $X1[m]$ fft of your $x1[n]$ sequence.  And, of course, the inverse fft of $X2[m]$ will be $x2[n]$ and the inverse FFT of $X1[m]$ will be $x1[n]$. I hope that helps. (By the way, you were smart to plot just the real part of your inverse fft.)

Answer (score 1):

The plot is correct. You have to remember that with the DFT the time domain is also periodic, so the left side of the plot represents time $t=0$ and the far right side represents time $t<0$. If you use fftshift the plot will look as you'd expect except that the middle of your plot will reresent time $t=0$.

Saw the edits you made to your code - I think you be skipping the first fftshift. I always use fftshift - I can't recall the difference between fftshift and ifftshift. See example below. Actually I think there is an error in your new code - it should be ifft rather than ifftshift.

```
NFFT = 4301;
AvIFFT  = ifft(FFTavg.dat,NFFT);   
plot(real(fftshift(AvIFFT)))
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use `fftshift()` above. As this fft is the result of an average, I cannot check with initial signal. Is it normal that it is very symmetric like this? Or did I make an error in the code?

Comment: Well, it depends on what your original time series is, so I can't say. You really need to show what the original time series is, even if it is averaged. You should look at the ifft of FFTavg.dat without any interpolation - your interpolated result should appear similar but interpolated i.e. a higher time sampling.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will try to average the time series and compare.

Comment: @user3406207 For your FFTavg.dat are the complex valued FFTs averaged or is it their magnitudes or something else?

Comment: This is how I averaged the ffts of my time series: `Y(:,i) = fft(dat1(i),Padding); avg = sum(abs(Y),2)/size(Y,2); FFTavg.dat = avg;`